# CSS Flexbox and responsive - pretty classic article layout - can be done without JS nor DOM fiddling?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

This is what I aim for :

[image]

This is the [code I tried](https://jsfiddle.net/x895wmg3/). It is the desktop first version and works. But not mobile, and I was told to code mobile first.
I would like to get both desktop and mobile 'choregraphies' set without JS if possible. Something complementary to flexbox is an option.

```css
html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 100%;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}


.col-m-1 {
 width: 8.333%;
}
.col-m-2 {
 width: 16.667%;
}
.col-m-3 {
 width: 25%;
}
.col-m-4 {
 width: 33.333%;
}
.col-m-5 {
 width: 41.667%;
}
.col-m-6 {
 width: 50%;
}
.col-m-7 {
 width: 58.333%;
}
.col-m-8 {
 width: 66.667%;
}
.col-m-9 {
 width: 75%;
}
.col-m-10 {
 width: 83.333%;
}
.col-m-11 {
 width: 91.667%;
}
.col-m-12 {
 width: 100%;
}




@media (min-width: 769px){
 .col-d-1 {
  width: 8.333%;
 }
 .col-d-2 {
  width: 16.667%;
 }
 .col-d-3 {
  width: 25%;
 }
 .col-d-4 {
  width: 33.333%;
 }
 .col-d-5 {
  width: 41.667%;
 }
 .col-d-6 {
  width: 50%;
 }
 .col-d-7 {
  width: 58.333%;
 }
 .col-d-8 {
  width: 66.667%;
 }
 .col-d-9 {
  width: 75%;
 }
 .col-d-10 {
  width: 83.333%;
 }
 .col-d-11 {
  width: 91.667%;
 }
 .col-d-12 {
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <article class="grid article">
    <div class="my-img-supclass col-m-12 col-t-4 col-d-4">
      <img src="img.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-m-12 col-t-8 col-d-8">
      <h2 class="article-h2"><span>a h2 title</span></h2>
      <p class="article-p">some content</p>
    </div>
  </article>
<body>
```

This does not work in mobile, the image gets completely at the bottom obviously since the 2nd div.

Comment: for the desktop view, does the pink pane scroll independently? or can it get taller/shorter? does it wrap around the green pane, or stay on the right half?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow all scrolls together. The pink pane stays on the right half, does not wrap around green. Maybe Ill just have my client (gf :) ) redesign :<

Comment: Please provide a [mre] in the question itself, not only on an external site. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon for toolbar button looks like `<>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use case for [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). The CSS-Tricks website has a [nice cheat-sheet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) for grid. The feature is supported by [all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid).

The idea is you'll define the `body` (or a container `div`) to display as a grid, with named grid regions (via `grid-template-areas`). The regions correspond to the image, the title, and the body.

Then, inside your media query, you can remap the grid layout.

I've set my media query to trigger at 800px so that when you run the stack snippet below, you should see the mobile view. If you click "full screen" on the snippet, you'll see the desktop view.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
      "hero-image article-title"
      "hero-image article-body";
}

.hero-image {
  grid-area: hero-image;
  background: lime;
}

.article-title {
  grid-area: article-title;
  background: yellow;
  color: red;
}

.article-body {
  grid-area: article-body;
  background: magenta;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    grid-template-areas:
        "article-title"
        "hero-image"
        "article-body";
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-image">image</div>
<div class="article-title">title</div>
<div class="article-body">body</div>
```

Comment: Looks idoine! Any precaution to put the grid container itself inside a flex container?

Comment: @AIDoubt as far as i know, that wouldn't be a problem.